# rails, mock before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stub, before-filter

I have a number of models that should be "finished" in a couple of days after creation.
I've made a before_filter that finds all models that should be finished and finishes them.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to write spec for the same.
The models are validated like this: ( pseudo validation ):

```
validates :till, date: { later_than: 2.days.from_now.to_date, earlier_than: 8.days.from_now.to_date }
```

the before_filter looks like this:

```
@models = Model.where(['till <= ? AND finished = ?', Time.now.to_date, false])
   @models.each do |model|
     model.update_attributes(finished: true)
   end
end
```

So to make my before_filter find the tested model I can save it with fake date(i.e 5.days.ago) by passing `validate: false`

But in before filter the `update_attributes` call will return false since model has a wrong date.

Could you please advice how can I make before_filter skip the validations in a context of a single test case?

Comment: is it that your validation should just fire on create and not on update?

Comment: omg, so obvious .. feel free to add this as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a `:on => :create` to your validation, so that calling `update_attributes` in your `before_filter` won't trigger it.